# pandas dataframe transform by specify column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as following:

```
city    ci    freq    value    c_id
fz    460-01    d1    4    1
fz    460-02    d2    2    1
fz    460-03    d3    8    1
fz    460-07    f1    1    2
fz    460-09    f2    9    2
xm   460-11    a    4    5
xm    460-13    d2    2    7
xm    460-14    d3    8    7
xm    460-21    f1    5    8
xm    460-22    f2    7    8
```

I want to transform it by python, the result as following:

```
city    c_id    ci_list    freq_list    value(mean)
fz    1    460-01,460-02,460-03    d1,d2,d3    7
fz    2    460-07,460-09    f1,f2    5
xm    5    460-11    a    4
xm    7    460-13,460-14    d2,d3    5
xm    8    460-21,460-22    f1,f2    6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby(['city', 'c_id']).agg(ci_list=('ci', list), freq_list=('freq', list), value_mean=('value','mean')).reset_index()^M


  city  c_id                   ci_list     freq_list  value_mean
0   fz     1  [460-01, 460-02, 460-03]  [d1, d2, d3]     4.66667
1   fz     2          [460-07, 460-09]      [f1, f2]     5.00000
2   xm     5                  [460-11]           [a]     4.00000
3   xm     7          [460-13, 460-14]      [d2, d3]     5.00000
4   xm     8          [460-21, 460-22]      [f1, f2]     6.00000
```